# Тире в сложном предложении для выражения следственных отношений между блоками

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение, бсп

*Вот как работает мышление клиента при покупке. **Клиент хочет получить некое желаемое будущее, это желаемое будущее ассоциируется с вашим товаром — клиент хочет получить ваш товар.***

Первые два простых предложения связаны отношениями перечисления, третье связано следственными отношениями с первыми двумя в составе единого блока. Допустимо ли использовать тире для выражения этих отношений, то есть для выражения отношений не между двумя частями БСП, а между блоками.

Comment: Один из примеров, когда излишнее умствование только вредит... В синтаксисе нет понятия "блока". Тире, естественно, ставится. Наверно, лучше добавить слово "следовательно", раз уж это "следственные отношения".

Comment: Клиент и человек – одно и то же лицо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант редактирования:**

*(1) Клиент хочет получить некое желаемое будущее, (2) это  будущее ассоциируется с вашим товаром — (3) и в результате человек хочет приобрести ваш товар.*

**Пояснение**

Я думаю, что значение следствия  для предложения (3) по отношению к предложениям (1) и (2) сложно выразить в БСП, поэтому желательно добавить союз и наречие.

Постановка тире (а не запятой) по правилам возможна, в этом случае тире  обозначает увеличенную паузу.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

3. Иногда сложносочинённое предложение распадается на две смысловые части, между которыми ставится тире:

Answer (score 1):

Без союзов это предложение выглядит как цепочка из трех звеньев (в таком порядке мысли и желания возникают в голове клиента):

**Клиент хочет получить некое желаемое будущее — это желаемое будущее ассоциируется с вашим товаром — клиент хочет получить ваш товар.**

Если вы считаете важным указать, что клиент на основании первого и второго приходит к третьему, то это нужно указать:

**Клиент хочет получить некое желаемое будущее, это желаемое будущее ассоциируется с вашим товаром, — (и) в результате клиент хочет получить ваш товар.**

Я бы поставил запятую и тире (предложение распадается на два логических блока — то, что Розенталь называет «переломом» конструкции).

Comment: Интересная идея — поставить два тире, чтобы подчеркнуть, что указанные мысли последовательно возникают в голове клиента. Но соответствует ли это нормам пунктуации? В этом случае ведь второе предложение легко принять за вставную конструкцию, поскольку она обособляется так же, причём по стандартному правилу.

Comment: Соответствует ли это нормам пунктуации? Не знаю, но подобные примеры встречал, постараюсь найти. Второе предложение легко принять за вставную конструкцию? Нет, пожалуй. Вставная конструкция разрывает простое предложение, а тут разные  предложения.

Comment: Вот примеры цепочек: Скудные сведения были доставлены по самой ненадежной цепочке: ремонтники ― шофер полуторки ― полевой эвакогоспиталь. [Илья Бояшов. Танкист, или «Белый тигр» (2008)] ; Ниже рассказ о цепочке: брак между близкими родственниками ― генная мутация ― нарушенный белок ― больной ребенок ― поиск лекарств. [И. Лалаянц. Молекулярный лего, или некоторые вопросы биоэтики // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

Comment: Но в ваших примерах тире соединяет однородные члены, а не части сложного предложения. Для однородных членов, действительно, у Розенталя есть правило: _Для усиления выразительности и интонационного членения допускается постановка тире между однородными членами предложения: Все говорят одно и то же: Распутин — царица — немцы — война — революция (М. Г.); Вспоминается цепь событий: приезд Веры — знакомство — разговоры о литературе и искусстве — объяснение — отказ — расставание._ (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97)

Comment: Да, я расширил толкование. Формальных доказательств  у меня нет.

Answer (score -1):

Допустимо ли тире? Так оно обязательно здесь, чтобы указать на следствие! И, думаю, между первыми двумя предложениями вместе запятой лучше поставить союз "и".

Comment: Вопрос в том, допустимо ли тире именно в данном случае — когда имеет место не обычное БСП с двумя частями, а БСП с тремя частями, в которых первые две связаны отношениями перечисления, а третья связана следственными отношениями с первыми двумя в составе единого блока.

Comment: В вашем сообщении непонятно, "вместе с запятой" или "вместо запятой"? Исправьте опечатку.